# Why am i getting these angular errors?

Tags: angular, angular-material, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to implement angular ag grid. Can anyone help me? I am stuck here from 2 days.

Error: src/app/appComponents/triage/triage.component.html:97:21 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'length' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-paginator'.

1. If 'mat-paginator' is an Angular component and it has 'length' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-paginator' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

97      <mat-paginator [length]="100" [pageSize]="100" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 100]">
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/appComponents/triage/triage.component.ts:38:16
38   templateUrl: './triage.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component TriageComponent.

Error: src/app/appComponents/triage/triage.component.html:97:53 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'pageSizeOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-paginator'.

1. If 'mat-paginator' is an Angular component and it has 'pageSizeOptions' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-paginator' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

97      <mat-paginator [length]="100" [pageSize]="100" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 100]">
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/appComponents/triage/triage.component.ts:38:16
38   templateUrl: './triage.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component TriageComponent.

Error: src/app/commonComponents/side-menu/side-menu.component.html:15:19 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.

15     <a mat-button [routerLink]="'/admin'" class="dash-spacer" routerLinkActive="active">
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs because the Angular compiler does not recognize the property "length" that is being used in the template for the "mat-paginator" component.

To fix this error, you can try the following steps:

Import the "MatPaginatorModule" module from the "@angular/material" library in the app.module.ts file:

```
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatPaginatorModule
  ],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Add the "MatPaginator" directive to the "mat-paginator" element in the triage.component.html file:

```
<mat-paginator [length]="dataSource?.data?.length"
               [pageSize]="pageSize"
               [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
               (page)="onPageChange($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

Add the "MatPaginator" directive to the "mat-paginator" element in the triage.component.html file:

```
<mat-paginator [length]="dataSource?.data?.length"
               [pageSize]="pageSize"
               [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"
               (page)="onPageChange($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

This error occurs because the Angular compiler does not recognize the "routerLink" directive that is being used in the template for the "a" element.

To fix this error, you can try the following steps:

Import the "RouterModule" module from the "@angular/router" library in the app.module.ts file:

```
<a mat-list-item routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
```

By importing the "RouterModule" module and using the "routerLink" directive, the compiler should now recognize the directive and the error should be resolved. Make sure to import the necessary components and modules to ensure that the "routerLink" directive is available.

To resolve this warning message, you can add the "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the "@NgModule" decorator of the module that declares the component that uses the "mat-paginator" element.

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    // ...
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

By adding the "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the schemas array, you are telling Angular to ignore any unknown custom elements in your component template, including the "mat-paginator" element. However, make sure that the custom element is defined and available to use in the browser.